# JasperReports. How to count records in time interval and display it in chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a table for storing event information. When event is launched it creates new record in table. Each record contains timestamp value that represents time when event was launched.

For example:

**Table** EVENT_DATA 
**integer** ID
**varchar** NAME
**timestamp** STARTIME
etc...

What I need to do is to calculate amount of events in each hour of a day and display them in a chart. Is it possible to achieve this only by means of iReport or JapsersoftStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to work the query which will return your data.

I haven't tested it but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM startime), count(id)
FROM EVENT_DATA
WHERE startime BETWEEN :a AND :b
GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM startime)
```

Of course the query depends on your database.

Comment: Thank you! That is enough for me. I've understood an idea.